# OCAML sum types with non-primitive datatype constructor

Tags: types, constructor, sum, ocaml

I want to create a sum type that acts as a dictionary such that

```
type dict = Dict of Map.Make(String)
```

Is it possible in OCaml ?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. If you need a dictionary than the [ocaml standard library includes one](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-.ocaml/libref/Hashtbl.html).

Comment: I want to create a sum type with a dictionary constructor. For e.g. type t= Int of int. Similarly i want something like, type t = Dict of Map(String) ? something like this.

Answer (score 4):

`Map.Make(String)` is a module expression that returns a module, not a type. In this case, the map type generated by the application of the functor `Map` is `'a Map.Make.(String).t`. It is therefore possible to write

```
type 'a t = Dict of 'a Map.Make.(String).t
```

There are other two important remarks at this point. First, to use this type, it will be required at some point to actually compute the module expression to obtain a module. That is why, it is more idiomatic to write

```
module D = Map.Make(String)
type 'a t = Dict of 'a D.t
let empty = Dict D.empty
```

Second, having only one constructor for a type sum is a sign that this type sum might be not necessary. For instance, the type sum could be replaced here by a type alias:

```
module Dict = Map.Make(String)
type 'a t = 'a Dict.t
```

Comment: Note that depending on the functor each invocation can return a unique module. Using `type 'a t = Dict of 'a Map.Make.(String).t` would make it impossible to create instances of this type since that requires to invoke the functor a second time (resulting in a new unique module). So always use `module D = Map.Make(String)` to avoid nasty surprises.

Comment: Ocaml functors are applicative, so two different applications of the same functor to the same module will yield two equal modules: `type t = A of int Map.Make(String).t  module D = Map.Make(String) let x = A D.empty` works as expected.

Comment: not always equal: `module type M = sig end  let next = let x = ref 0 in function () -> incr x; !x  module U (M : M) = struct let id = next () end module M = struct end  module A = U(M)  module B = U(M);;  A.id == B.id;;` Can't make an example with a unique type from memory but I did run into such a case.

Comment: To be more precise, type levels components are equals when a functor is applied twice to the same module, not value levels. Another important point is that modules are deemed equal as functor input if they share the same path. In particular, for any functor `F`, `F(struct  … end) ≠ F(…)` because `struct … end` is an anonymous module. But, yes, I agree that in general defining the module `M=F(X)` first is a good idea.